# Issue with setting the selected value inside mat-chip

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-material2

I'm facing an issue in a scenario where I had first saved all the values from the form and now want to open the values for edit,but the mat-chip doesnt show the selected value.

Have created the mat-chip in HTML as below

[image]

the above html on browser looks as below
[image]

I'm getting theme.value as it can be seen from the image,then why the selected value is not been set properly on edit,where is that i'm going wrong this is first time i'm working with material please guide

I had given a try by setting selected as true for mat-chip still it didnt work

Posting the code block

```
<mat-form-field [ngClass]="selectedTheme.length === 0 ? '' : 'active'" appearance="outline" class="common-multiselect-dropdown">
   <!-- <mat-label>Theme</mat-label> -->
   <mat-select aria-owns="theme" placeholder="Select theme" aria-label="Select theme" name="activityTheme" [(ngModel)]="selectedTheme" [formControl]="theme" multiple ngDefaultControl (selectionChange)="onThemeChange($event)">
   <mat-select-trigger class="common-multiselect-trigger">
      <mat-chip-list>
         <mat-chip class="common-multiselect-chip" *ngFor="let selectedValue of theme.value;let index = index" [removable]="true" (removed)="onSelectionRemoved(selectedValue)">
         {{ selectedValue.theme | titlecase}}
         <mat-icon matChipRemove class="momenta-icon">cancel
         </mat-icon>
         </mat-chip>
      </mat-chip-list>
   </mat-select-trigger>
   <mat-option aria-controls="theme" [attr.aria-label]="theme" *ngFor="let theme of themeList" [value]="theme">
   {{theme.theme}}
   </mat-option>
   </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
{{ theme.value | json }}
```

Comment: Please post your code as code blocks in your question, not image, thanks.

Comment: And as you are working with objects, you will want to look into angular's `compareWith`

Comment: I was trying to post the code block but it was not getting formatted hence posted the image @AT82,have posted the code block please have a look

Comment: @AT82 thanks for idea of compare it worked